# Cohomology of a homotopy pullback of groupoids

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, tensor-products

Let $\Lambda \stackrel{F}{\to} \Omega \stackrel{G}{\leftarrow} \Gamma$ be a diagram of groupoids and functors and $\Gamma \times_\Omega \Lambda$ the homotopy pullback. We will regard all these groupoids as spaces and compute the cohomology with coefficients in some field.

There should be a map
$$ C^*(\Gamma) \stackrel{\mathbb{L}}{\otimes}_{C^*(\Omega)} C^*(\Lambda) \to C^* (\Gamma \times_\Omega \Lambda)$$
from the derived tensor product to the cohomology of the homotopy pullback.

Is this map an equivalence?

Comment: I think so, that's Eilenberg-Moore, isn't it?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, we would need that $\Omega$ is simply connected.

Comment: You're right, local coefficients come in so trivial actions would be necessary to recover this for ordinary cochains.

Comment: So are you saying the statement is false?

Comment: I don't have any counterexample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,  consider the multiplication by $2$ map on the integers. The homotopy fiber is  two points.  But the derived tensor  product (for $\mathbb Q$ coefficients) is  $\mathbb Q \otimes^{L}_{\mathbb Q[x]} \mathbb Q[x] =  \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Any clue under which requirements the about statement will be true for general spaces (other requirements that $\Omega$ simply connected)?

Comment: I saw somewhere that the Eilenberg Moore SS converges strongly iff the fundamental group of the base acts unipotently on the homology of the fiber-- so maybe that hypothesis will help.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure this is exactly controlled by the convergence of the EMSS. I think Brooke Shipley has a nice paper about this, IIRC.